# How to project an addFields attribute in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document in my collection `testdb` that I want to match to and looks like:

```
{
    "student": {
        "first": "Joe",
        "last": "Johnson"
    },
    "semester": [{
        "semesterName": "Spring2021",
        "courses": [{
                "title": "Calculus 1",
                "professor": "Erik Paulson",
                "TA": "Paul Matthews"
            },
            {
                "title": "Computer Science 1",
                "professor": "Dennis Ritchie",
                "TA": "Ken Thompson"
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

I want to match on the `title` attribute in the `courses` array and return the `professor` attribute without all of its nesting.

So I have the following query:

```
db.testcol.aggregate([
    { $match: { "semester.courses.title" : "Calculus 1" } },
    { $project: { "professor" : 1, "_id" : 0 } },
    { $addFields: { "professor":  "$semester.courses.professor" } },
]);
```

but I seem to be getting an output of just `{ }` when I want an output of `{ "professor" : "Erik Paulson" }`.

Can somebody explain why this is happening and how I can fix it? My logic is that I am using `$addFields` to set the new `professor` attribute to be the `professor` attribute inside of the array of `course` objects whenever there is a match to the desired `course title`. I am then using `$project` to return only the new attribute.

Comment: The `$project` stage is removed the `semester` field before the `$addFields` can extract data from it.

Comment: how can I get around this? Do I just switch the ```$project``` and ```$addFields```?

Comment: You dont need the `$project` stage. Also see this post: [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation:
Mistake is in your `$project` stage. property `professor` is two level inside the document which must be referenced as `semester.courses.professor`. Accessing it as `professor` will result in empty value.

So you can fix it using below query. Try this:

```js
db.testcol.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$semester" },
    { $unwind: "$semester.courses" },
    { $match: { "semester.courses.title" : "Calculus 1" } },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": 0,
            "professor": "$semester.courses.professor"
        }
    }
]);
```

Output:

```js
{
    "professor" : "Erik Paulson"
}
```